# What is the relation between the size of the DB and the size of /var/lib/postgresql/data

Tags: postgresql

I want to perform actions before my disk is running out of space.
For that, I have to periodically check the size of my DB.

I can query the size of the DB (for example by running `pg_database_size( current_database()` ). The problem is, that the size of the postgres folder itself, (`/var/lib/postgresql/data`) is much bigger. (almost twice the size of the response that I get from my query.

**edit:** I run the `du -h /var/lib/postrgesql/data` and `pg_database_size()` on my data base few times, when the database was with different data.

Here are the results :

```
du -h /var/lib/postgresql/data  | pg_databse_size()
-----------------------------------------------------------
3.7G                            |(1582MB)
5.8G                            |(2490MB)
6.3G                            |(2699MB)
7.8G                            |(4245MB)
8.0G                            |(4400MB)
8.9G                            |(5330MB)
58G                             |(41GB)
```

Those are the file from my `du -h` command (when running this command, `pg_database_size()=41 GB`

```
du -h data/
4.0K    data/pg_replslot
4.0K    data/pg_wal/archive_status
16G     data/pg_wal
4.0K    data/pg_stat
12K     data/pg_multixact/offsets
12K     data/pg_multixact/members
28K     data/pg_multixact
4.0K    data/pg_logical/snapshots
4.0K    data/pg_logical/mappings
16K     data/pg_logical
12K     data/pg_notify
168K    data/pg_subtrans
7.4M    data/base/12993
7.4M    data/base/1
7.6M    data/base/12994
20K     data/base/pgsql_tmp
43G     data/base/16384
43G     data/base
40K     data/pg_stat_tmp
4.0K    data/pg_twophase
584K    data/global
4.0K    data/pg_snapshots
4.0K    data/pg_commit_ts
20K     data/pg_xact
4.0K    data/pg_serial
4.0K    data/pg_tblspc
4.0K    data/pg_dynshmem
58G     data/
```

**Is there any correlation between the size of the DB and the size of `/var/lib/posgresql/data`?**

How can I predict the size of the data folder based on the DB size?

Comment: If you have more than one database, then obviously `/data` includes **all** databases whereas `pg_database_size(current_database())` only reports the size of the **current** database.

Comment: I have only one database

Comment: So what do the multiple lines refer to? Please add the actual directory names next to your `du` output. And why do you list the output of `pg_database_size()` multiple times if you only have a single database? What does `\l+` in `psql` show you?

Comment: *"I want to perform actions before my disk is running out of space."* PostgreSQL is the wrong tool for that.

Comment: Thank you all. I edit my qustion. @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' - What will you do? I need to do stuff in my code (for example delete some entries)

Comment: I still don't know what the multiple lines for `pg_databse_size()` should indicate, but you clearly have one database that is 43G - I assume it's the last line that shows `41GB`. The difference between 43 and 41 could be the difference between using [`GB` and GiB`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte)

Comment: @Kfir: I use our monitoring system to alert us to all disk space issues. Automatically dealing with database disk space issues is only rarely the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a correlation between database size and the space used by the data directory, but “correlation” is a statistical term, and statistics won't tell you if you are currently running out of disk space.

What you actually want to know is if you can determine the size of the PostgreSQL data directory based on the size of the databases, right?

The answer to that is “no”: there are many other data in the PostgreSQL data directory, and they are not related to the database size.

- The most obvious example are the transaction logs (WAL files), which are in the `pg_wal` subdirectory (`pg_xlog` in older PostgreSQL versions).

  The amount of WAL generated is proportional to the amount of data modifications to the database, which has nothing to do with the size of the database.

  Normally, WAL size is limited by `max_wal_size` (`checkpoint_segments` in older versions), but that is no hard limit. For example, if WAL archiving has a problem, old and un-archived WAL file will not get deleted. They can accumulate pretty quickly if you have a lot of data modification activity and can fill your disk. This is completely unrelated to the size of your database.
- A second example are *temporary files*, which are stored in the `base/pgsql_tmp` subdirectory of your data directory. Such files are generated to store intermediary query data if they don't fit into `work_mem` RAM.

Comment: Thank you! so, in order to determine the size of the PostgreSQL data directory, I will add the size of my DB and the `max_wal_size`. Then I will add some buffer because it is a "soft limit". But still, I have "extra" 2GB in the `/data/base` folder (I edited the question)

Comment: Yes, of course. There are many other data. The point is that you cannot determine the size of the data directory from knowing the size of the database(s). I just added another important point where the sizes can diverge substantially.