# pg_profile data mismatch between growth database and growth tables && indexes

Tags: postgresql

We use pg_profile (postgres 14) and sometimes Growth data does not match with growth tables && indexes.

For example:

- Database Growth = 12gb
- Top growing tables sum = ~1.1gb
- Top growing indexes sum = ~6.5gb

Docs says "Growth - database growth during report interval (*pg_database_size()* difference)".

Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57462449/22470792 says that logs/temp_files/wal_logs doesn't affect pg_database_size.

I expected the data between growth database and growth tables and indexes to be the same.

Where could the data (~4.4gb) have been lost?

Comment: in the linked answer is nothing of that kind, he expliains that in the directory of the database will be much more files than the expected size

Comment: In linked only describe what pg_database_size use for count spase.